# Xubuntu 22.04 - any way to disable gamepads from rumbling/force-feedback?

Tags: kernel, gamepad, xbox-one

This PC is for gaming and retro-gaming and uses lots of different emulators.

Amongst its controllers I'm using two generic Xbox One controllers with the xone driver at https://github.com/medusalix/xone#readme

The devices are:-
20d6:2005 PowerA Xbox Series X Wired Controller OPP Black
24c6:581a ThrustMaster, Inc. XB1 Classic Controller

And they work and are detected except for a severe issue with the rumble feature. Sometimes when these gamepads rumble in a game, they become unresponsive and continue to rumble uncontrollably until the gamepad is unplugged.

In some games it's possible to disable the rumble feature - which I think is a better workaround than trying to debug the joypads or to remap them as generic controllers.

My question is whether it's possible for me with some command or config file to disable the rumble feature fundamentally across the system - perhaps at the kernel level?

Separately I will ask the driver developer on their discord if it can be added as a feature - or documented if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workround for this.

Although the 'Xbox Accessories' tool on Windows 10 didn't give the option to update the firmware on these two generic controllers (20d6-2005 and 24c6-581a) it did enable the rumble to be turned off (in the Configure... menu).

I'm not sure *exactly* what I did, but I first attached a Microsoft-brand controller (045e-0b12) which had the rumble feature ticked. I then connected the other two controllers and their rumble feature was unticked too - without me having to untick it. When I moved all 3 controllers back to Linux none of them rumble anymore. And they are all working as expected and no longer affected by this problem.